# Encrypting Data in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to Encrypt the data that is being stored in SharePoint Online?

We would like to encrypt any data that is being sent out from our office to be store in SharePoint Online so we can assure the data is secure and not vulnerable if decide to store sensitive or customer data.

Answer (score 1):

The E* licenses for Office365 SSL protect the SharePoint online trafic.

But if you want the content itself encrypted, then there is no support in SharePoint.

When should the content be encrypted?
When should it be decrypted?
What should SharePoint expose to the users?

If everything is going to show up in SharePoint as encrypted data, then I'm not sure SharePoint will provide any value.

Answer (score 0):

The only method I'm aware of for encrypting SharePoint data is to encrypt the database using TDE.  I doubt O365 does this.  You can also use RMS, but that only secures the file as it is coming out of a Doc Lib (and RMS protection is removed when being placed in a Doc Lib).  The reason for this is that the data would not be searchable by the search service if it was encrypted while sitting in a Doc Lib.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a tool from cipherpoint that says it does all that you want. Eclipse for SharePoint online is the 3rd party product. I am going to be evaluating it in the coming weeks. Will let you know what I find but you could ping them and see if they have what you are looking for. it is at cipherpoint.com